# how to show the tweet count and twitter button in my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, .net, twitter

Hi I know its a silly question but i have no other go..how to get the tweet counts and a tweet button below that count...I searched twitters developers site and took a piece of code,which shows the count and a tweet button below that.But if i change the url of page it wont work..kindly help please..

**URL to get tweet counts**

https://twitter.com/Fayyaztravels

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-
url="http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=https://www.twitter.com/FayyazTravels"                                                           data-via="FayyazTravels" data-lang="en"
 data-related="anywhereTheJavascriptAPI"                                                     data-count="vertical">Tweet</a><script>                                            
!function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if 
(!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = 
"https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } } 
(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find something useful [HERE](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons)